# Some data on facebook.stackoverflow not facebook specific

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, facebook.stackoverflow

I'm not sure if this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but on the [Facebook Stack Overflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/) homepage the elements in the right bar aren't all facebook-specific. My favorite/ignored tags cover all of SO. The recent tags are specific to facebook, but the recent badges aren't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All user settings are inheritted from Stack Overflow.  Your accounts aren't distinct.

Badges, being per-user, are also not distinct between the sites.

This is very much [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).  Facebook.StackOverflow is a view onto Stack Overflow, not a truly separate site like an SE 2.0 is.